# How can I set execution date in HttpSensor (Airflow)?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I try to pass execution date to httpsensor operator.

```
is_api_available = HttpSensor(
    task_id='is_api_available',
    http_conn_id='data_available',
    endpoint='api/3/action/date= {{I want to set date in here}}'
)
```

I can get execution date parameter in python operator like this:

```
print("my start date : ",kwargs['execution_date'] )
```

it works but how can I get it in other operators?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jinja template with the variable {{ ds }}, it format the datetime as YYYY-MM-DD

for more macros you can see at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

```
is_api_available = HttpSensor(
task_id='is_api_available',
http_conn_id='data_available',
endpoint='api/3/action/date={{ ds }}')
```

api/3/action/date=2022-06-25